# How can I use the custom swipe capabilities of SwipeCellKit for a custom cell created from a .xib file?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a custom cell made using a CustomCell.xib as well as a class that goes with it. The way I use it is by registering my custom cell in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
categoryTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
configureTableView()
```

Then I set the cell like this:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCategoryCell

Now, I want to use a CocoaPod called [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) which makes the cells capable of swiping actions as well as adding an image and making the swipe fully customizable.

In order to use this! I have to change the downcasting of the cell to be `as! SwipeTableViewCell`.

So my question is: is there a way that I can use both my custom cell and the SwipeCellKit CocoaPod?

My initial thoughts were to go to the table view controller and make the custom cell directly there and not in a custom .xib file, or to copy and paste the code given in the GitHub project.

Any thoughts?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `SwipeTableViewCell` as the **superclass** of your custom cell instead of `UITableViewCell`.

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class CustomCell: SwipeTableViewCell {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot and it seems really simple, however I have a UIViewController that inherits from a UITableViewDelegate as well as UITableViewDataSource. When I replace these two with SwipeTableViewCell i get the following error : Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'SwipeTableViewCell'.

Comment: UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource are protocols, not classes. You should only make the custom cell a subclass of SwipeTableViewCell.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean but still for some reason it does not work. I have tried multiple things but none of the work. To be clear I don't have any errors thrown but the cells are not capable of swiping.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the cell?

Comment: Okay so I have done that before and now it worked because I also inherited from SwipeTableViewCellDelegate. Thank you a lot Tamás!